# Creating folders with multiple subfolders

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a script that creates folders A through Z and in each folder there is also 26 more folders, A through Z based on the depth.
I have a general idea of how to script is going but don't know how to implement the folder making part.

```
import os
import itertools

#create the base directory
basepath = '/path/to/alphabet'
os.mkdir(basepath)

#setup alphabet list
#long to crate full directory structure
#alphabet = 'A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z'  
alphabet = 'A B'   #short alphabet for testing purposes
alphabet = alphabet.split()


depth = 4

def recurse(path, depth):
    for letter in alphabet:
        folder_name = os.path.join(path,letter)
        #os.mkdir(path + letter)
        print(path + letter)
        if depth > 1:
            recurse(path + letter, depth - 1)
        
recurse(basepath, depth)
```

Comment: your function seem to be ok, what is actually wrong? except that you do not use folder_name but create incorrect string with + operator instead, your code works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a general idea of how to script is going but don't know how to implement the folder making part.

All you need to do is called [`os.mkdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) - which you have commented out.

As `Ruli` commented, your script works when you actually make use of your `folder_name` variable.

```py
import os
import itertools

#create the base directory
basepath = '/path/to/alphabet'
os.mkdir(basepath)

#setup alphabet list
#long to crate full directory structure
#alphabet = 'A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z'  
alphabet = 'A B'   #short alphabet for testing purposes
alphabet = alphabet.split()


depth = 4

def recurse(path, depth):
    for letter in alphabet:
        folder_name = os.path.join(path, letter)
        os.mkdir(folder_name)
        print(depth, folder_name)
        if depth > 1:
            recurse(folder_name, depth - 1)
        
recurse(basepath, depth)
```

Output:

```
4 /path/to/alphabet/A
3 /path/to/alphabet/A/A
2 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/A/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/B
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/A/B/B
3 /path/to/alphabet/A/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/A/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/B
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/A/B/B/B
4 /path/to/alphabet/B
3 /path/to/alphabet/B/A
2 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/A/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/B
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/A/B/B
3 /path/to/alphabet/B/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/A/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/A/B
2 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/B
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/B/A
1 /path/to/alphabet/B/B/B/B
```